# php eval function and performance

Tags: php

Im creating a web app where I want all of the responses to the user stored in a language file for easy editing.  So Im using eval() to manage dynamic messages lik so:

```
$msg = 'Hello $user, your favorite color is $color';

$colors =  array("red","green","blue","yellow");
$users =  array("bob","craig","ted","dirty sanchez");

foreach($users as $key => $user){

 $color = $colors[$key];
 eval("\$newmsg = \"$msg\";");
 echo $newmsg;


}
```

Im wondering if this is the best approach or if there is a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never use that damn eval if not necessary!
Your code won't work, you should use [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) for your purpose.

```
$messageFormat = 'Hello %s, your favorite color is %s';

$colors =  array("red","green","blue","yellow");
$users =  array("bob","craig","ted","dirty sanchez");
foreach($users as $key => $user){
   $color = $colors[$key];
   $actualMessage = sprintf($messageFormat, $user, $color);
   echo htmlentities($actualMessage);
}
```

Assuming you're using this for comments or other user-supplied text, I've added [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) to prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: @websiteguru: There are two reasons why you ought not use eval if you can avoid (and you can avoid nearly always):
a) it is a security risk. eval allows executing PHP. If a user could smuggle malicious input into eval, he could execute PHP (and thus, he would have nearly full control over your server.)
b) eval is slow, really slow. And eval code is hard to understand. Even though I would call myself an experiences PHP developer it still took some time, till I got what your code does, whereas Lekensteyn's code is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is the printf function.
you can define a string and have %s as place holder for a string.

then call

```
printf($variable, $string1, $string2, $string);
```

the first %s gets replaced by $string1 and so on.

in your very example i would use vsprintf which returns the string and you can give an array so you can feed it what every array of params and input string you like

heres your example:

```
   <?
$msg = 'Hello %s, your favorite color is %s';
$colors =  array("red","green","blue","yellow");
$users =  array("bob","craig","ted","dirty sanchez");
foreach($users as $key => $user){
 $color = $colors[$key];
 $newmsg = vsprintf($msg,array($user,$color));
 echo $newmsg."\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way:

```
<?php

$msg = 'Hello [USER], your favorite color is [COLOR]';

$colors =  array("red","green","blue","yellow");
$users =  array("bob","craig","ted","dirty sanchez");

foreach($users as $key => $user)
{
    $color = $colors[$key];

    $newmsg = str_replace(array('[USER]', '[COLOR]'), array($user, $color), $msg);
    echo $newmsg;
}
?>
```

Comment: While not what I was looking for, this is interesting.  How would this compare in performance to the sprintf solution?  Specifically if there were a large amount of variables used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$colors =  array("red","green","blue","yellow");
$users =  array("bob","craig","ted","dirty sanchez");
$messages = array_combine($colors, $users);

foreach ($messages as $color => $user)
{
     echo "Hello $user, your favourite color is $color";
}
```

Using array_combine which creates arrays in the format $keys => $values making the following array:

```
"red" => "bob",
"green" => "craig",
"blue" => "ted",
"yellow" => "dirty sanches"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function

```
$msg = 'Hello @user, your favorite color is @color';
echo strtr($msg, array('@user'=>'bob', '@color'=>'red'));
```

Output:

```
Hello bob, your favorite color is red
```